# Adjust height between Tablayout title text and icon

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I there any way to reduce the distance between the title text and the icon of `TabLayout` like in Google plus where the icons and text title have at least no distance. I have searched , but couldn't find anyway till now.

[image]

**EDITED**

This is how I am setting icon and title:

```
 tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_more_horiz_white_24dp);
 tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setText("More");
```

And this is my `TabLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />
```

Comment: are you using any custom layout for your TabLayout?

Comment: did you found a solution to this?

Comment: did u found any solution for this ?

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

you can try this code, it works for me

```
for (i in 0 .. tabLayout.tabCount) {
        val params = tabLayout.getTabAt(i)?.view?.getChildAt(0)?.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams?
        params?.bottomMargin = 0
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i)?.view?.getChildAt(0)?.layoutParams = params
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`TabLayout` has been introduced to help developers conform to Material Design standards. In that case it is appropriate tab height, padding between icon and text and icon and text size. Look into [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs) in order to get familiar with them.

However if you really don't like the padding (and don't want to build application according to Material Design guidelines) you can change it.

You can use [@user13 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39326570/6507689). That way You can pass your layout.

However remember that if you would like to build `TabLayout` more dynamically and use it's `TabLayout.Tab#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)` and `TabLayout.Tab#setIcon(int)` you must use layout like that:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/icon"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" />
```

Look at the identifiers `@android:id/icon` and `@android:id/text1`. If you add those ID's the `TabLayout` your layout will work with `TabLayout` class code. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(int)) for more info.

Comment: Sure thnx , let me try this.

Comment: You use "weight", which only works in LinearLayout parents and you also use "layout_below" which only works in RelativeLayout parents. I think this should be wrapped in LinearLayout and "layout_below" property can be removed.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me! +1

Comment: How to make this work while using MVVM with databinding?